# View Counter should increase only after a specified time for each IP address in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

For my blog website, I have created a view counter but it increases every time the page refresh. I want to create a View Counter that should increase only after a specified time for each IP address has passed for each post. Here is my code:

`PostController.cs-`

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    Post post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

    post.View++;

    _context.Update(post);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return View(post);
}
```

---

Thank you.

Comment: Look like you need a table to store the post view from which IP. If the IP is new or the IP exceeds a certain timeframe as mentioned for the post, add an record to the new table as reference and the post count.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little ambiguous.
If u want to update count after a certain time you can use [stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-8.0) or [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-8.0).
Or if you want to update it on ipchanged then you can invoke this method on ipchanged using events([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/703294/c-trigger-and-event-when-there-is-a-change-in-a-va))

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a separate table to store visits along with IP, as in the example below

first create a model(table) :

```
public class PostViewCount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public int ViewCount { get; set; }

    public string IP { get; set; }

    //add post navigation property
    // public Post Post { get; set; }

}
```

then after adding to `DbContext` and apply Migrations you can use it as follows :

**! i used `DbContext` Directly in `Controller` But You can move this code into your service**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
 {
     Post post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

     await UpdatePostViewCount(id);

     return View(post);
 }


private async Task UpdatePostViewCount(int postId)
{
    string ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

    var postView = await _context.PostViewCounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.IP == ip && p.PostId == postId);

    //We will check if the visitor is exist?.
    if (postView is not null)
    {
        //if exist just update visitor view count
        postView.ViewCount++;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return;
    }

    //if dose not exist create new record in PostViewcount table                   
    var postViewCount = new PostViewCount()
    {
        IP = ip,
        PostId = postId,
        ViewCount = 1
    };

    _context.PostViewCounts.Add(postView);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

}


//Get Post View Count
public async Task<(int totlaViewsWithRepeaterts,int totlaViewsWithoutRepeaterts)> GetPostViewCount(int postId)
{
   var totlaViewsWithRepeaterts = await _context.PostViewCounts
        .Where(p => p.PostId == postId).SumAsync(x => x.ViewCount);

    var totlaViewsWithoutRepeaters = await _context.PostViewCounts
        .CountAsync(p => p.PostId == postId);

   return (totlaViewsWithRepeaterts, totlaViewsWithoutRepeaters);
}
```